# How to publish a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a android application which wants to connect to C# server application via a web service. I have develop the web service. But I don't know how to publish it to connect to my android application in the phone. Can any one tell me how to publish a.NET web service to internet?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the [web application project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [web site project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t.aspx) containing the web service.